# Date format change in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, windows

I have an issue while exporting content to excel. If it's an `MM/dd/yyyy` date then excel is taking it as a date format. If we format into `dd/MM/yyyy` then it's considered to be a custom format in excel.

Below is my code:

```cs
private string GetFormattedDateforCreation(string datestring) //yyyyMMdd
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(datestring))
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
       return DateTime.ParseExact(datestring, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-CA")).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    }
}
```

Excel Generate

```
Clipboard.Clear();
    
// Bulk insertion of Data into Trigger Element Excel
bool multiselect1 = dgvElement.MultiSelect;
dgvElement.MultiSelect = true;
dgvElement.SelectAll();
dgvElement.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText;
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dgvElement.GetClipboardContent());
var resultElement = System.Convert.ToString(Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
dgvElement.ClearSelection();
dgvElement.MultiSelect = multiselect1;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application XCELAPPELEMENT = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook XWORKBOOKELEMENT = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet XSHEETELEMENT = null;
object misValueElement = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

XCELAPPELEMENT = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

XWORKBOOKELEMENT = XCELAPPELEMENT.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath);
XCELAPPELEMENT.DisplayAlerts = false;
XCELAPPELEMENT.Visible = false;
XSHEETELEMENT = XWORKBOOKELEMENT.ActiveSheet;

XSHEETELEMENT.Paste();
XWORKBOOKELEMENT.SaveAs(Path.Combine(basePath, _frmSwip.OutputExcelFilePath, "SWIP_ElementsDeclencheurs_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_mm_yyy HH_ss_mm")), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
XWORKBOOKELEMENT.Close(true);
XCELAPPELEMENT.Quit();
try
{
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(XSHEETELEMENT);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(XWORKBOOKELEMENT);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(XCELAPPELEMENT);
}
catch
{
    return "0";
}
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question to clarify what behaviour you want for each of the date formats you mentioned?

Comment: Hi Tim, In the excel if you type the date in the format MM/dd/yyyy then the format will change automatically as date. Similarly if i tried from c# then it's consider only the string in MM/dd/yyyy but if I forcefully convert as a dd/MM/yyyy then the excel consider as a string.So how we could change the date format in our c#.